# Jquery dataTables con Combobox de filtro

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy usando jquery dataTables y quiero agregar un combo de filtrado para un campo especifico en la ubicación a continuacion de "Search"...es posible esto?. Ya ví ejemplos que se pueden agregar comboxes en el footer, debajo de cada columna de la tabla y filtrar de esa forma, pero estéticamente no me gusta y ademas, solo necesito un combo de filtrado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No soy muy bueno con jQuery pero puedes agregar un combobox arriba de tu tabla y lanzar un evento al momento de cambiarlo.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#tablaDetalle').DataTable({
          "bPaginate": false,
          "bLengthChange": false,
          "bFilter": true,
          "bInfo": false,
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          initComplete: function() {
              var div = $('#tablaDetalle_wrapper');
              div.find("#tablaDetalle_filter").prepend("<label for='idDepartamento'>Departamento:</label><select id='idDepartamento' name='idDepartamento' class='form-control' required><option>Seleccione uno...</option><option value='1'>  FRITURAS</option><option value='2'>REFRESCOS</option></select>");
              this.api().column(0).each(function() {
                  var column = this;
                  console.log(column.data());
                  $('#idDepartamento').on('change', function() {
                      var val = $(this).val();
                      column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                          .draw();
                  });
              });
          }
      });
  });
```

**Edición**: Lo agregué a la altura del campo de búsqueda

Te dejo el [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxyx0150/7/)

Comment: Funciona correctamente y es una opción que ya manejaba. El inconveniente (estético) es que el combo está fuera del dataTable. yo quiero que saber si se puede dejar a la derecha o izquierda del "Search" y a la misma altura

Comment: Listo, lo modifiqué y lo puse a la altura del campo de búsqueda... Saludos

Comment: Excelente @ed-garcia !...eso es lo que queria!

Comment: Aun esta abierta la pregunta para ayudar? @EdGarcía

Comment: @PabloContreras AFAIK el usuario encontró en la respuesta lo que buscaba, pues así lo señaló en el comentario.

Comment: No especifique bien. La ayuda sería para mí, esto es lo q quiero, pero a mi no me funciona. Uso: laravel 5.3 y postgresql.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, un poco distinto a el pero sin embargo lo resolví, el único problema q me queda es que el label me aparece encima del select y el select encima del filtro original de datatables.

Comment: Revisaste el jsFiddle?, A mi también me estaba pasando, pero lo puse al mismo nivel todo.